# I'm not a person, yet I'm quite clever

Tags: riddle

I'm not a person, yet I'm quite clever,

With language skills that are better than ever.

I can talk to you, but not face to face,

And help you with problems in any case.

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be

> Any kind of chatbot AI or digital assistant, like Bard, Siri, Cortana, Alexa, ChatGPT etc.

Specifically with "language skills better than ever", I'm going to go with

> LaMDA, which one of the developers said could supposedly converse at the level of a human child.

Comment: Yep you got it! The riddle was written by the model itself.